# How to use a specific TabBarItem with a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I've created a TabBarController, but don't want the usual gray/blue icons with it, so I created another class inheriting from UITabBarItem. So the question is : how can I use these custom icons/items with my tab bar (add them and link them to some view controllers) ? Programmatically or with IB of course.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each view controller that you put into your tab bar controller, assign your custom tab bar item to the view controller's `tabBarItem` property

Comment: Could you give me an example ? Let's imagine I have a class containing :    `UITabBarController * tabBar;  CustomItem * item1, * item2;  UIViewController * controller1, * controller2;`    What must I do here ?